# How to use Facebook iOS SDK to send invite using presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession

Tags: ios, facebook

I have followed the tutorial and examples at developer.facebook.com.

I am using `[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:` to ask the user to invite friends. The dialog pops up and everything seems to work correctly, the dialog returns success. But no invite shows up.

I can add that other facebook actions such as getting all friends for a user and posting in feed works.

Any clues? Is this a known bug? Am I missing some permissions?

Comment: Invites are only shown in App Center. Do you not see them there?

Comment: Yes I see them there. Is this the case that invites is only visible in app center? Nowhere else?

Comment: I'm noticing the same thing. That is LAME. Who would actually drill down and check that?

Comment: I am wondering how candy crush saga can send request/invite like they do ...

Comment: Because "candy crush" is a game, games are with special privileges.
They can use invite friends functionality:
 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2